# jQuery: execute script when site is completely loaded EXCEPT for some stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that you can execute your script when the page is loaded respectively if the page has loaded all images and stuff.

My issue is, I've got some 3rd party scripts which most likely have a delay before executing since they don't start until 5 seconds into loading the page.

Can I somehow execute my script when all images are loaded, but not all scripts have been executed to create a workaround for this?

Thanks for any ideas

***EDIT***

See my accepted answer, just putting the scripts before the other scripts worked out just fine. Thanks

Comment: @depperm the 3rd party scripts are amazon payments and tawk.to scripts for example. Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: You understood correctly. You mentioned they most likely have a delay, have you tried using them? Is there a delay?

Comment: @depperm well yes, I know from the firefox performance analysis in the inspector, that they start executing very late into the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what these scripts do. If they are not firing on document load but immediately than you have to put your code before calling these scripts (also your script must execute immediately instead of page load).

I don't think there is `setTimeout(function(){}, 5000)` in these scripts.

Keep in mind that scripts are executed from top to bottom.

Comment: so if I got your point here, I just need to make sure my framework loads the script in question before the scripts that take so long?

Comment: @Yorrd Yes. Also, if you see that some scripts are taking too long to load, move them to the end of page

Comment: okay, I'll try tonight. The thing is, until now, I believed that my script is executed first anyways, but I'll double check and report back.

Comment: @Yorrd So than what's the problem? If you don't want to make pre-changes for external scripts, than why you need that?

Comment: I want to make a loading animation for my page which covers it while it loads. Of course, it shouldn't be covered for 10 seconds when only the live chat or some tracking script loads for example.